# Why can't I output a combination of three keys using AutoKey on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: hotkeys, ubuntu-17.04, autokey

Here's what I've done so far:

- mapped <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> to `keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<f4>")`, works
- mapped <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> to `keyboard.send_keys("<alt>+<f4>")`, works
- mapped <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> to `keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<alt>+<f4>")`, doesn't work

Incidentally, `keyboard.send_key("<super>")` doesn't work either. Not sure if that is related to the original issue or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided by [xircon on Github](https://github.com/autokey-py3/autokey/issues/98)

`import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'alt', 'F4')`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 is the newest version supported by Autokey, if I remember correctly, may be the reason.